# Caldigit TS3 Plus USB Ports not working on Macbook, but Video Works

Tags: thunderbolt

Using the t2linux guide, Ubuntu kernel 5.13.15-t2-j-bigsur, the USB ports (and audio device, card reader, ethernet port) don't work on a Caldigit TS3.

Video (displayport) works fine.

The Thunderbolt device is authorized (verified via `boltctl`)

There is simply nothing reported in dmesg regarding the new usb controller or anything related to that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here turned out to be that I had `pcie_ports=compat` on my kernel boot parameters.

This prevented any downstream pcie (thunderbolt) devices from taking charge and being downstream pcie things.

Removing that argument, running, `update-grub`, and rebooting allowed all the ports to work. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566886/pcie-ports-compat-why-port-can-be-treat-as-bridges/593152